# Replace every <img> tag with itsown custom data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to replace every occurrence of `<img>` tag in a html message, with a unicode value stored as a custom attribute.

Sample message:

```
<img data-uni-val="&#x1F603;" src="path/to/img1.png" class="emoji"/>hello,
<br /> <img data-uni-val="&#1F604;" src="path/to/img2.png" class="emoji"/>
```

I need to replace every emoji `<img>` with its unicode value where it stored as custom attribute.

```
$('<div />')
.html(chatText).find('img.emoji')
.replaceWith('someval').end().html()
```

Using above code I can find and replace every img's with a string, but not able to replace with `data-uni-val`.

I tried:

```
$('<div />').html(chatText).find('img.emoji')
.replaceWith($(this)
.data('data-uni-val')).end().html()
```

Is there any simple way to solve this?

Comment: Please to consider formatting and including the div you talk about in your markup

Comment: What do you expect the markup to be after it's been replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that the attribute `data-uni-val` should be accessed using `$(this).data('uni-val')`.

Furthermore, you could just use `.replaceWith(fn)` to perform the conversion.

```js
$('.emoji').replaceWith(function() {
  return $(this).data('uni-val');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img data-uni-val="&#x1F603;" src="path/to/img1.png" class="emoji"/>hello,
<br /> <img data-uni-val="&#x1F604;" src="path/to/img2.png" class="emoji"/>
```

Comment: You're correct (and the snippet obviously works), but you failed to mention the important part which is correct naming in the `data()` "key". That's the reason it didn't work in the firs place.

Comment: Working fine, `.data('uniVal')` is the better way i guess

Comment: @abhijith I can't say it's better.. obviously both work. But it's the "Standard recommended way"

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, the `.data()` function uses a different "name" than the name you use inside the element markup. It's a camelCase without the 'data' and without the hyphens.

Try `.data('uniVal')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.emoji').each(function(){
   var str = $(this).attr('data-uni-val');
   $(str).insertAfter($(this));
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div img").each(function(){
$(this).removeClass('emoji').addClass($(this).attr('data-uni-val'));
});
```

Comment: While this is technically correct, it would be great if you could add a little more explanation to your answer to make it even more useful for everyone. Also a little hint: You can use `.data('uni-val')` to access the data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you want:

```
jQuery('.emoji').each(function(){
var str = jQuery(this).attr('data-uni-val');
jQuery(this).replaceWith(str);
});
```